# XSS validation: Is it safe to check only if value contains <> and %3C %3E

Tags: html, xss

I've been doing server side XSS validation. Here is what I found to use:
List of forbidden attributes: `javascript:,mocha:,eval(,alert(,vbscript:,livescript:,expression(,url(,&{,&#,/*,*/,onclick,oncontextmenu,ondblclick,onmousedown,onmouseenter,onmouseleave,onmousemove,onmouseover,onmouseout,onmouseup,onkeydown,onkeypress,onkeyup,onblur,onchange,onfocus,onfocusin,onfocusout,oninput,oninvalid,onreset,onsearch,onselect,onsubmit,ondrag,ondragend,ondragenter,ondragleave,ondragover,ondragstart,ondrop,oncopy,oncut,onpaste,ontouchcancel,ontouchend,ontouchmove,ontouchstart,onwheel`

However they seem to be too strict since some correct values such as "™" are considered as illegal if I use this list.

I'm thinking if to check only value doesn't contain any of those characters like '<', '>', "%3E", "%3C" would be safe to prevent XSS attack?

Comment: Don't try to homeroll xss prevention. It won't work, and there will be constant vulnerabilities. If you don't need full HTML, then just use something like `innerText` to avoid the whole thing and not have to use any filtering. If you do need HTML, you should be doing client-side validation anyway (due to inconsistencies in browser rendering, it's very hard to make a server-side application that can stop XSS on all browsers), but if not, you should be using a well-established library like [HtmlSanitizer](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.html.sanitizer.HtmlSanitizer.html)

Comment: What characters are safe and what characters are not are **highly**, **massively** dependant on where **exactly** the user input gets inserted.

Comment: @Aplet123 we already have client side validation for it. What I'm trying to do is to prevent someone using curl send us illegal values. I have no control where those values are rendered. I need to prevent them being persisted into database if they contain any script.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to block any of those characters, long lesson-learned you're just cutting out other language support potentially and you can work with these characters safely.

Imagine we have a chat-box, as this is where these may get used most often in a textarea. The user can pass the following `<html></html>` and if it wasn't handled properly every user receiving the message will open up a new HTML document inside this chat (scary).

This gets handled on the client side fortunately, some hacks to make it "text-only".

When dealing with login you could regex check username, if that passes you can then SQL search the username if match is made check if password matches too by encrypting the password just given and matching it, no match get out.

I've never needed to block characters or treat anything special knowing proper encoding/decoding (escape practices and whatnot). Maybe this will help your search.